# How to log unanswered call? Ubuntu 18 + Asterisk 16 + FreePBX 15

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I have done a fresh installation with Ubuntu 18 + Asterisk 16 + FreePBX 15

But I found by default it is not logging unanswered call, should I add “unanswered = yes” in res_odbc_custom.conf myself?

or there is option via FreePBX web GUI?

```
  Name:   asteriskcdrdb
  DSN:    MySQL-asteriskcdrdb
    Number of active connections: 2 (out of 5)
    Logging: Disabled

root@pbx:~# cat /etc/asterisk/res_odbc_custom.conf

root@pbx:~# cat /etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; Do NOT edit this file as it is auto-generated by FreePBX. All modifications to ;
; this file must be done via the web gui. There are alternative files to make    ;
; custom modifications.                                                          ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
;
; This file is part of FreePBX.
;
;    FreePBX is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    FreePBX is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with FreePBX.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
;
; Copyright (C) 2012 Astrogen LLC (USA)

#include res_odbc_custom.conf
#include res_odbc_additional.conf

root@pbx:~# cat /etc/asterisk/res_odbc_additional.conf
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
;          Do NOT edit this file as it is auto-generated by FreePBX.             ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; For information on adding additional paramaters to this file, please visit the ;
; FreePBX.org wiki page, or ask on IRC. This file was created by the new FreePBX ;
; BMO - Big Module Object. Any similarity in naming with BMO from Adventure Time ;
; is totally deliberate.                                                         ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
[asteriskcdrdb]
enabled=>yes
dsn=>MySQL-asteriskcdrdb
pre-connect=>yes
max_connections=>5
username=>freepbxuser
password=>84c79e53323853481c3755c7edd3abed
database=>asteriskcdrdb
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should check cdr.conf

```
; Define whether or not to log unanswered calls that don't involve an outgoing
; party. Setting this to "yes" will make calls to extensions that don't answer
; entries will not be created. Unanswered Calls which get offered to an
;unanswered = no
```

Comment: cdr.conf is an empty file as I followed the installation guide on https://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Installing+FreePBX+15+on+Debian+9.6

You may see the last few command:
touch /etc/asterisk/{modules,cdr}.conf
cd freepbx
./start_asterisk start
./install -n

Comment: tried to add unanswered = yes in the empty cdr.conf file, reload by "fwconsole reload", using the asterisk command "cdr show status", it is still the same - "Log unanswered calls:       No"

Comment: i think have be some section, see cdr.conf.sample.